# Why is $\int_0^1 \operatorname{sgn}(\sin(2^n\ \pi t))^2 dt$ equal to 1?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

The integral given is
$$\int_0^1 \operatorname{sgn}(\sin(2^n\ \pi t))^2 dt$$
for $n=0,1,2,...$

The indefinite integral is given as
$$\frac14 t\left(\;\operatorname{sgn}(\sin(2^n\pi t))^2 + 3\;\right)$$ by WolframAlpha. If I plug in in $0$ and $1$, that gives me $3/4$, but it should be $1$. If I enter the definite integral from $0$ to $1$, it gives me $1$ as desired.

Why is this integral equal to $1$?

Comment: Do you mean the integral given is $\int_0^1 sgn(\sin(2^n\pi t)dt$?

Comment: I made an edit!

Comment: n is a natural number, n= 0,1,2,...

Comment: Sorry, I made another edit.

Comment: $\text {sgn}(\sin 2^n \pi t)^2 = 1$ for all $t$ except countably many points where it equals $0.$

Comment: Can you explain why that is the case?

Comment: The sgn function will return 1 whenever the argument is positive, and zero when it is zero. The only times when the function will return zero in this cae is when $2^n t$ is an integer, which will occur $2^n$ times, which is countable.

Comment: Oh my god, you're right! I mean, the anti-derivative from Wolfram is in fact the one given by you, and the integral becomes $\frac 34$ upon evaluation at the endpoints : when, for rather obvious reasons, this function differs from $1$ only at countably many points, so the integral should be $1$. Of course Wolfram is wrong : it remains to be seen why. I would love a very nice answer here, +1, see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=indefinite+integral+of+sgn%28sin%282%5En+pi+t%29%29%5E2) for the Wolfram Alpha query.

Comment: Ah ok, I see the problem, the function isn't absolutely continuous so the fundamental theorem of calculus doesn't apply i.e. the integral need not be equal to the endpoint value differences of the anti-derivative. There is no derivative at some parts of the interval, including at the endpoint, which probably explains it.

Comment: To make the wolfram-alpha integral make sense you need to calculate $\lim_\limits{t\to 1} \frac 14 t(\text{sgn}(\sin(2^n \pi t))^2 +3) - \lim_\limits{t\to 0} \frac 14 t(\text{sgn}(\sin(2^n \pi t))^2 +3)$

Comment: Thanks for the answers! What I don't understand yet is the fact that $sgn(\sin(2^n \pi t)$ could be negative, ie. when n=4 and t = 0.9. Then the sign function would return -1. How do I account for that?

Comment: your function is $\text{sgn}(\sin (2^n\pi t))^2.$  When $\sin(2^n\pi t) < 0, (\sin (2^n\pi t))^2 >0$

Comment: The Wolfram function has derivative equal to your function everywhere except at finitely many points.  So do not say "the Wolfram antiderivative is wrong".  Instead say: "this application of the fundamental theorem of calculus is wrong."

Answer (score 1):

With the usual definition of $\def\sgn{\operatorname{sgn}}$ $\sgn$, which is

$$\sgn(x) = \begin{cases}
1,&x > 0\\
0,&x = 0\\
-1,&x < 0\\
\end{cases}$$
we get that the value of $\sgn^2$ is 1 except at the zeros of $\sin$:

$$\sgn(\sin(2^n \pi t))^2 = \begin{cases}
0,&\text{ if } 2^nt \in\Bbb Z\\
1,&\text{ else }\\
\end{cases}$$
For $t\in[0,1]$ the zeros are at $\{k/2^n \ | \ k\in\Bbb Z\cap[0,2^n]\}$ which is a set of measure zero.  Therefore

$$\int_0^1 \sgn(\sin(2^n \pi t))^2 dt = \int_0^1 dt =1$$

Comment: Can you figure out where $\frac 34$ comes from? Just wondering, I was about to finish writing an answer when I realized that I don't have an explanation for the appearance of $\frac 34$.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\sgn{\operatorname{sgn}}$

> Can you figure out where $\frac34$ comes from? [From a comment]

Well, maybe the problem is that the integrand can be parsed in two different ways.  In my 1st answer I parsed it as $\sgn^2\sin$, but one can also parse it as $\sgn\sin^2$.  However that makes no difference because $\sgn^2 (f(x)) = \sgn (f^2(x))$ for any real-valued $f$.

So no, I have no idea where the 3/4 comes from.  Maybe it's a glitch in WA, which is unlikely.

So let's drop that square and go

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \sgn(\sin(2^n \pi t)) dt
&= \underbrace{\int_0^{1/2} \sgn(\sin(2^n \pi t)) dt}_{\textstyle=A_n}
+ \underbrace{\int_{1/2}^1 \sgn(\sin(2^n \pi t)) dt}_{\textstyle=B_n}
\end{align}$$
Then substitute $x=1-t$, $dx=-dt$ in the second integral:

$$\begin{align}
B_n &= \int_{1/2}^1 \sgn(\sin(2^n \pi t)) dt \\
&= -\int_{1/2}^0 \sgn(\sin(2^n \pi (1-x))) dx \\
&= \begin{cases}
-\displaystyle\int_0^{1/2} \sgn(\sin(2^n \pi x)) dx, & n \geqslant 0\\
+\displaystyle\int_0^{1/2} \sgn(\sin(\pi x)) dx, & n=0 \\
\end{cases}\\
&= \begin{cases}
-A_n, & n \geqslant 0\\
A_n = B_n = 1/2, & n=0 \\
\end{cases}\\
\end{align}$$
So the integral will be either 1 if $n=0$ or it will be 0 if $n>0$.

---

So still no idea what to make of that $3/4$.... One could use it to forge a new question, like:

> Find values $C$ such that
> $$\int_0^1 \sgn(C+\sin(2^n \pi t)) dt\ =\ \frac34$$

---

Comment: Exactly , I see no reason why the $\frac 34$ comes, this is just something weird!